# Apply ColorData scheme for Plot from green to red

Tags: plotting, color

I'd like to apply a ColorData to this plot:

```
\[ScriptCapitalM] = 
  MixtureDistribution[{0.55, 0.35, 
    0.1}, {DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 0}], 
    NormalDistribution[0.25, .05], 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 1}]}];

Plot[{CDF[\[ScriptCapitalM]]@x}, {x, -.001, 1.001}, Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Costs", Bold, 40], 
   Style["CDF(Costs)", Bold, 40]}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, 30], GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["HTML", "MidnightBlue"])]
```

that starts from green (left) to red (right). I've checked the available schemes but apparently none matches my objective. Any ideas how to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define the `ColorFunction` to be a function of the values in the plot. If you allow this to be an RGBColor function you can let it take in the value of the x coordinate and define the colour scheme as you need:

```
\[ScriptCapitalM] = 
MixtureDistribution[{0.55, 0.35, 
0.1}, {DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 0}], 
NormalDistribution[0.25, .05], 
DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 1}]}];

Plot[{CDF[\[ScriptCapitalM]]@x}, {x, -.001, 1.001}, Filling -> Axis, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}}, 
Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["Costs", Bold, 40], 
Style["CDF(Costs)", Bold, 40]}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, 30], GridLines -> Automatic, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
ColorFunction -> (Function[{x}, RGBColor[x, (1 - x), 0]])]
```

[image: from green to red]

Comment: I'd like the red to dominate. I used: `ColorFunction -> (Function[{x}, RGBColor[x, 0.25*(1 - x), 0]])` but this makes the colors really dark. Can you please tell me how to make them more clear? Thanks

Comment: The fourth slot in `RGBColor` allows you to specify the Opacity, this may help to lighten it a little. You can also user the `Lighter` function around the `RGBColor` function

Comment: You could also use: `RGBColor[x, (1 - Sqrt[x]), 0]` or some other power of `x`.

Comment: Just a final question: If I wanted to catch all the intermediate colors, i.e orange, yellow, etc... How can I do it?

Comment: The it's probably easiest to use `ColorFunction -> (Function[{x}, Hue[x]])` or some function within the `Hue` command.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `LinearGradientFilling`:**

*Historical note:*

```
WolframLanguageData["LinearGradientFilling"
 , {"VersionIntroduced", "DateIntroduced"}]
```

[image]

---

```
ℳ = 
  MixtureDistribution[{0.55, 0.35, 
    0.1}, {DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 0}], 
    NormalDistribution[0.25, .05], 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 1}]}];

Plot[{CDF[ℳ]@x}
 , {x, -.001, 1.001}
 , Filling -> Bottom
 , FillingStyle -> LinearGradientFilling[{Green, Red}, Right]
 , PlotRange -> All
 , PlotStyle -> None
 , Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}
 , FrameLabel -> {
   Style["Costs", Bold, 40], Style["CDF(Costs)", Bold, 40]
   }
 , FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, 30]
 , GridLines -> Automatic
 , GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]
 ]
```

---

[image]